# Question on Random Probability with greatest integer function

Tags: probability

Let $x$ be chosen at random from the interval $(0,1)$.

> What is the probability that: $$[\log_{10} 4x]-[\log_{10} x]=0?$$

Here $[x]$ denotes GIF.

---

My efforts on this:

$4x≥10$ i.e. $x≥2.5$ for $$[\log_{10}4x]$$
and $x≥10$ for
$$[\log_{10}x]$$
would result into value other than $0$.

But $x$ lies in $(0,1)$. So for any value of $x$ between $0$ to $1$ will satisfy the given equation.

So probability should be $1$.

Is this a correct solution?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: 4x≥10 i.e. x≥2.5 for $$[log_{10} 4x]$$  and  x≥10 for $$[log_{10} x]$$ would result into value other than 0. But x lies in (0,1). So for any value of x between 0 to 1 will satisfy the given equation. So probability should be 1. Is this a correct solution?

Comment: Your efforts must be a part of the question. Please check my edit.

Comment: Concerning your effort: If e.g. $x=0.5$ then $\log_{10}x$ is negative and $\log_{10}4x$ is positive, leading to different GIF. So the equation is *not* satisfied for every $x\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \in [10^{-k}, 10*10^{-k})$ we have $[\log_{10}(x)]=-k$

But only for $x \in [10^{-k}, 2.5*10^{-k+1})$, we have $[4\log_{10}(x)]=-k$ too

So the probability that the two is equal is $\frac{2.5-1}{10-1}=\frac16$

Answer (score 1):

We can write the following:
$$[\log_{10} x] = \sum_{n \geq 1} -n \times I\{x \in [10^{-n}, 10^{-n+1})\}$$
Hence we have:
$$[\log_{10} 4x] - [\log_{10} x] = 0 \iff \exists n \geq 1: x \in \left[10^{-n}, \frac{10^{-n+1}}{4}\right)$$
In conclusion:
$$P\{[\log_{10} 4x] - [\log_{10} x] = 0\} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \left(\frac{10^{-n+1}}{4} - 10^{-n}\right) = \frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: $I$ is the indicator function, $n$ is an integer

Comment: Last equation thanks to the uniform distribution of $x$.